# Get-запрос на несуществующую страницу

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть функция добавления видео по ссылке. Пользователь вводит адрес и через JS идет AJAX запрос на адрес, которые ввел пользователь. Как определить есть ли такой адрес в интернете или нет. Если адреса нет, то выскакивает ошибка

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) "

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('get', 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+adress+'?alt=json&v=2', true);
 xhr.onload = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (~~(xhr.status / 100)) == 2) {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if(data != ''){

             // код
            }
      }
   }
  xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, кросс-доменные запросы запрещены, хотя, в случае различных API могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо дополнительно обрабатывать вариант 400 статуса:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get','https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+'ваш adress'+'?alt=json&v=2' , true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr.status==200){//xhr.status=200  is *OK*
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if(data != ''){
                alert('all right!');
            }              
        }else{//xhr.status==400 is * (Bad Request)*
            alert('Error :Bad Request');
        }
   }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PdMju/

Comment: так все равно в консоль выводится  ошибка, как сделать, что-бы она не выводилась

Answer (score 1):

jsonp

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
    },
    200: function() {
      alert("ok");
    }
  }
});
```

На работоспособность не проверял.